# Azure Functions: Allocation of memory and CPU between slots in consumption plan

Tags: azure-functions

How is CPU and memory allocated between the primary slot and staging slot on an Azure Function running under a consumption plan? I *thought* it was an even split, but that's not what I've seen out in the wild. I was also unable to find this information in the docs.

Comment: @DorisLv your answer did not answer this question. I will leave this open. My question has nothing to do with scale out.

Comment: It would be better to understand if you know consumption plan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan

Answer (score 0):

It not appropriate to say it's an even split.

The consumption plan scales the functions dynamically depending on workload. So the resources are allocated according to demand.

> When you're using the Consumption plan, instances of the Azure Functions host are dynamically added and removed based on the number of incoming events.

By the way, Function apps running under the Consumption plan only one slot is allowed.